# xcode tells errors when validating iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, validation, error-handling

I'm getting the following two errors when trying to validate my app.

It is an iPhone SpriteKit Game.

[image]

I set "devices" to iPhone.

I also tried to delete the `Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)` but it tells me the exact same error.

Comment: Once check that your Bundle identifier is matching with your Code singing. If it is successfully matched just Force quit Xcode and try

Comment: My Bundle identfier is the same as in itunesConnect. Is it essential that the identifier is "com.company.appname"? because mine is just "appname". I also have no idea how to change the BundleID in itunesConnect. -> I did not distribute the app so I should able to change it in itunesconnect but i can't or do not know how.

I tried again - but the same errors

Comment: Thanks! the budnle identifier was the problem. is has to be "com.company.appname" .. for some reason i thought that this does not matter.